# C# Access BindableObject properties

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a CollectionView with a few products. Now I added a TapGestureRecognizer to it with the following function:

```
private void product_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CachedImage image = (CachedImage)sender;

    var FileName = image.Source.BindingContext;
}
```

Now what I want is to get the FileName that is stored inside the BindingContext. If I set a breakpoint on this line: `var FileName = image.Source.BindingContext;` I can see in the BindableContext that there is a element called FileName, but when I do this: `var FileName = image.Source.BindingContext.FileName;`, It says:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'FileName'

So how can I access that property from the BindableObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declared type of BindingContext is `object`, which of course does not have a FileName property, so the C# compiler won't allow that.

If you want access to the actual object's type, you need to cast the `BindingContext` like this:

```cs
var viewModel = (MyViewModel)image.Source.BindingContext;
var filename = viewModel.FileName;
```

Substitute in the actual class name you use for the BindingContext that has FileName as a property.